# How to synchronize layout changes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I start more or less the development of android. I needed to create different layouts celon the android versions but now I would like to move a button. How to move this button on all the corresponding layouts whatever version of android at one time?
If there is already a post on it, sorry but I have not found it.

It's for the same screen size of course

Example: I have a linear layout of which I want to modify the right margin and I want this to do on the linear layout for versions <21 AND >21 by only doing it once and not two

Thanks !

Comment: Are you asking how to synchronize layout changes between different tablets?  Or different views on the same tablet?

Comment: For the same screen size

Comment: Can you post some sample code showing what you've tried.  That will make it clearer what you're asking.

Comment: i have add one example

Comment: You have to do it in each layout file you've defined.  If you have special layout files for different versions of Android you'll need to do it in multiple places-  which is why one should try to avoid doing that.  You can also try to minimize this via include files, keeping the common parts between multiple implementations of a layout to common files.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two layout files:

res/layout-v11/layout.xml AND
res/layout/layout.xml

You'll need to change the margin values in both files if they are hard coded.

Otherwise, you can have:

```
<LinearLayout
...
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/left_margin" >
```

and in res/values/dimens.xml have

```
<dimen name="left_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

and just change the value once in the dimens.xml file.

Comment: No, it's possible by using the dimens file.